# custom onError mapping rxjava while translating dto

Tags: rx-java

i have the following method that retrieves data from an external service. This data is received as a dto and i need to transform it to an entity object. Right now if there is a a problem ProviderNotReachableException is thrown,however i would like to throw a different exception when there is an errror in the translation logic, for e.g:  NumberFormat exception. As i am relative new to rxjava, i wanted to have advice from senior devs on the matter.
Thanks,
Jorge

```
 @Override
    public Observable<List<Itinerary>> itinerariesFromProvider(final FlightSpecification flightSpecification,
                                                               final String provider) {

        final Map<String, Object> params = getQueryParams(flightSpecification);

        return this.retrofitProviderService.itineraries(provider, params)
                .concatMapIterable(itineraryDtoList -> itineraryDtoList)
                .map(it -> {
                    logger.debug("Translating in thread: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    return itineraryTranslator.fromItineraryDtoToItinerary(it);
                })
                .toList()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnError(throwable -> new ProviderNotReachableException(format("For input string %s", provider), throwable))
                .toObservable();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `doOnError`, you can use `onErrorResumeNext` operator, it gets as param a function with `Throwable` as input (the `onError` we got) and returns `Observable` as output, with this operator you can map whatever exceptions you like to a different one using `Observable.error`:

```
.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                if (throwable instanceof ProviderNotReachableException) {
                    return Observable.error(new MyCustomException());
                } else {
                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                }
            });
```